# Создание видео из картинок на сервер (PHP)

Tags: php, веб-сервер, gd, gif

Здравствуйте. Была задача, создать Gif'ку на сервере из обычных картинок (jpg). Задача была решена с помощью php библиотеки GD, но после этого с толкнулся с проблемой отображения gifok на яблокоподобных устройствах и, как мне сейчас кажется, единственный выход это создать либо из готовой гифки, либо из фреймов, ИЗ которых создавалась гифка видео, чтобы вместо гифки показывать это видео пользователю. Как это можно реализовать на PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Ставим `ffmpeg` на сервер

и пишем следующий код

```
<?php 
  // ниже может быть любая команда на подобие exec, shell_exec и д.р.
  // да и в команду лучше вставить абсолютные пути
  system('ffmpeg -i animation.gif -s 420x300 animation.avi');
  if(file_exist('animation.avi') { 
     // проверяем фаил есть значит безошибок
     // хотя лучше взять вывод систем и проанализировать его на предмет корректной отработки
     echo "gif converted";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

При помощи того же ffmpeg:

```
<?
shell_exec("ffmpeg -framerate 0.5 -pattern_type glob -i 'pathToFile/*.jpg' \
  -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p pathToVideo/result.mp4");
?>
```

заменяем  *pathToFile* на путь в файлам,
*pathToVideo* на путь куда сохранить видео

после *-framerate* указывается частота кадров в секунду (0.5 значит показывать каждый кадр 2 секунды)